# Publishing encrypted files with Visual Studio 2010 ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encryption, clickonce

My project solution is located under an encrypted folder and when I publish a project the files will also be encrypted. I am trying to publish them to another server which gives me the error

*Failed to copy file 'C:...' to '\Server...'. Unable to add 'Application Files/...' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Application Files...'.  The specified file could not be encrypted.*

Is there a way to remove the encryption autmatically before publishing or some other way to solve this. I don't want to remove the encryption of the solution directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable encryption by typing this into commands promt

fsutil behavior set disableencryption 1

Or if you want to keep encrpytion on, I think you need need to make a common encryption certificate and import it to both your pc and server, then you will be able to publish the encrypted files across the network.

- Make a new [certificate](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/create-a-file-encryption-certificate-and-key/)
- Import it on both machines,
- Then goto the encryption certificate manager and select the certificate, you will be prompted to select your drives, Select your drives and wait till it updates your files.  Do this on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this is to copy the files to a folder that is not encrypted, run mage or mageUI to sign the deployment, and then copy them to the server. There is nothing in C/O that will handle encrypted folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

The file is encrypted already and so cannot be decrypted then encrypted when published.

Right click the file in Windows explorer, Properties. Under Attributes click Advanced. Deselect the checkbox for "Encrypt contents to secure data."